# Get json value parsed into an input field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I'm using this js for recovering some data from my database MYSQL and it works pretty fine.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() { // When the document is ready
    $("select#product1").on("change", function() { // We attach the event onchange to the select element
        var id = this.value; // retrive the product id
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php", // path to myphp file which returns the price
            method: "post", // POST request 
            data: "id=" + id, // I retrieve this data in my$_POST variable in ajax.php : $_POST[id]
            success: function(response) { // The function to execute if the request is a -success-, response will be the price
                $("input#total").val(response); // Fill the price
            }
        });
    });
}); </script>
```

In my input#total I get this value (for example):

[{"price":"5","time":"10"}]

how can I get just the price value or the time value?
I searched for some json parser but I'm not able to put it into my input.

This is my full HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="j_idt2">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select#product1").on("change", function() {
                var id = this.value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: "id=" + id,
                    success: function(response) {
                        var datashow = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                        $("input#total").val(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="product1" name="product1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
        <option value='17'>Product1</option>
    </select>

    <input id="total" type="text" name="total" class="form-control" />

</body>

</html>
```

This is what I get into my input field when I select product1 with $("input#total").val(response);

[{"price":"5","time":"5"}]

When I change this line:

**$("input#total").val(response);**

with

**$("input#total").val(datashow.price);**

I don't get anything.

My php seems to render properly my json. It just lookslike my response is not parsed or can't be stored in any way into a var.

Comment: Have you tried any calculation using Ajax or jQuery?

Comment: Yes I added the code and the explanation of the problem

Comment: You should parse your result with jQuery.parseJSON( response );

e.g var data =  jQuery.parseJSON( response );
$("input#total").val(data.price);

Comment: let me know if you have solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse you response using jQuery.parseJson 
e.g Change you code like this below

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() { // When the document is ready
    $("select#product1").on("change", function() { // We attach the event onchange to the select element
        var id = this.value; // retrive the product id
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php", // path to myphp file which returns the price
            method: "post", // POST request 
            data: "id=" + id, // I retrieve this data in my$_POST variable in ajax.php : $_POST[id]
            success: function(response) { // The function to execute if the request is a -success-, response will be the price
                      var datashow = JSON.parse(response);             
                 $("input#total").val(datashow[0].price);
            }
        });
    });
}); </script>
```

Hope this will solve your problem

/////////////////////// Tried with static response///////////

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="j_idt2">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var response = [{"price":"5","time":"5"}];
            $("input#total").val(response[0].price);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="product1" name="product1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
        <option value='17'>Product1</option>
    </select>

    <input id="total" type="text" name="total" class="form-control" />

</body>

</html>
```

And i get correct result.

Comment: var data = jQuery.parseJSON( response );  Console this data variable and show me the console result

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined(…)

Comment: that means response you are getting from php function or file has some error. kindly check your response first if response in correct format as you showed above than this should work.

Comment: it's not like this. I updated my issue with my full HTML code, please check it. :)

Comment: changed my answer try now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105493/discussion-between-k-uzair-and-ame).

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse();`

```
success: function(response) {
            var datashow = JSON.parse(response); 
            $("input#total").val(datashow.price);
          }
```

This must work if you are passing a Json from the server. And with your current code.

If you want the json to be auto parsed when you get it in success function then use `dataType: "json"` setting. So your code must be like below.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php", // path to myphp file which returns the price
        method: "post", // POST request 
        dataType: "json", // <--- setting dataType
        data: "id=" + id, // I retrieve this data in my$_POST variable in ajax.php : $_POST[id]
        success: function(response) { // The function to execute if the request is a -success-, response will be the price
            $("input#total").val(response.price); // The response would be already parsed
        }
    });
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, doing alert(datashow.price) just after JSON.parse(response) shows undefined. This is very strange...

Comment: can you show what is your response value? Also is your server code returning anything back?